# Where to get Initial EASA Class 1 Medical?

Tags: medical

Can somebody suggest a list of **EASA** medical centers, where I can get **Initial Medical 1**?
Any EASA county is OK.
I'll appreciate any links, thank you!

**Amendment:**
I've found lists of AMCs or at least medical examiners approved by CAA for the following countries: [UK](https://www.caa.co.uk/Commercial-industry/Pilot-licences/Applications/Medical/Apply-for-a-Class-1-medical-certificate/), [Spain](https://www.seguridadaerea.gob.es/LANG_CASTELLANO/prof_sector/medicina/centros/default.aspx), [Serbia](http://www.cad.gov.rs/en/strana/19261/aeromedical-centres-and-aeromedical-examiners), [Poland](https://www.ulc.gov.pl/en/aviation-personnel/aviation-examination-commission/2484-aero-medical-centres), [Finland](https://www.traficom.fi/en/transport/aviation/contact-information-aeromedical-examiners-and-aeromedical-centres), [Croatia](https://www.ccaa.hr/english/aero-medical-centres-and-examiners_75/), [Ireland](https://www.iaa.ie/personnel-licensing/aero-medical-section/aero-medical-centres), [Malta](https://www.transport.gov.mt/aviation/medical-services/authorised-examiners-3256), [Switzerland](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/bazl/en/home/specialists/training-and-licences/civil-aviation-medical-service.html), [Romania](http://www.caa.ro/pages/aviation-medicine), [Greece](http://www.hcaa.gr/en/licensing-training/degrees-licences/medical-issues/), [France](https://www.ecologique-solidaire.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/SITE-MINISTERIEL-ANNUAIRE%20AeMC%2021022017.pdf), [Danmark](https://www.trafikstyrelsen.dk/da/Luftfart/Tilladelser-individuelle/Helbredsgodkendelse#)

Full list of EASA countries and list to it's CAAs can be found [here](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/international-cooperation/easa-by-country?easa_relationship%5B0%5D=field_easa_country_mbmo_target_id). And some of examiners all over the EASA [here](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Medical_assessor_0.pdf).

Does somebody know about other countries like France, Germany...? I have not found any lists of AMCs approved by CAA or at least medical examiners for these countries

Comment: Which country you want to do the medical?

Comment: Edited. Any EASA country

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the country you are going to take the medical examination.

Normally, the national civil aviation authorities of each European country will have this listing. For instance, in Spain, AESA publishes [here](https://www.seguridadaerea.gob.es/LANG_CASTELLANO/prof_sector/medicina/centros/default.aspx) the approved medical centers where applicants can take their initial and successive examinations.

So I suggest to first find out the authority from your country and always make sure with the medical center that you are going to take a certified EASA Class 1 medical examination.

Comment: BTW, in case you are planning to take the medical examination in Spain I strongly do not recommend "CENTRO DE INSTRUCCIÓN DE MEDICINA AEROESPACIAL (CIMA)". The center is run by military personnel and their philosophy is that any deficiency will be used against you to fail the examination. Me and many colleagues have been affected by this :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of UK Aeromedical centres is available on the [Apply for a Class 1 medical certificate](https://www.caa.co.uk/Commercial-industry/Pilot-licences/Applications/Medical/Apply-for-a-Class-1-medical-certificate/) page on the CAA website

(I'll include a copy of it as soon as I've worked out how to post a table here)